# Create an asset in Pimcore through web service

Tags: json, pimcore

I am very new to Pimcore, but I was going to the API to see if it would meet my requirements. What I would like to do is add assets to Pimcore through it's web service API. I have found that this should be possible ([link](https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Web_Services/index.html#page_Create_New_Asset)), but I don't see how since it is not very well documented. It is possible to provide me an example on how to upload an image as asset to Pimcore through the web service API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's example url:

http://website-domain.dev/webservice/rest/asset?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY

And there's example post data:

```
{"data":"<<BASE 64 ENCODED FILE>>","parentId":1,"type":"image","filename":"image.jpg","path":"\/","mimetype":"image\/jpeg","userOwner":"2","properties":null,"metadata":[]}
```